# How to replace false with 0 and true with 1 in column when boolean masking is applied

Tags: python, pandas

for example i have column in dateframe 'df' named 'SPEED' . SO df[df['Speed']>50] will simply put true and false according to condition in that column.  But i want to put 0 instead of false and 1 instead of true. How to do that?

Comment: `df['Speed'].gt(50).astype(int)`?

Comment: `*1` will help :)

Comment: what for greater than equal to?

Comment: `ge` in place of `gt`